# Rows into Columns Oracle pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using oracle 10g pl sql, I want to transpose rows into columns but the columns should be dynamic and not hard-coded.

```
select *
from
 "EnumerationValue"
   pivot
    (count("pkEnumerationValueId")
      for "Text" in (select "Text" from "EnumerationValue" where "fkEnumerationId"=6));
```

I found this query by searching but its giving me error.

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Then I tried like this

```
VARIABLE g_ref REFCURSOR
DECLARE
 v_sql VARCHAR2(32767);
  BEGIN
   v_sql := 'select "Text"';
   FOR rec IN
     (select "Text" from "EnumerationValue" inner join "Enumeration" on "Enumeration"."pkEnumerationId"="EnumerationValue"."fkEnumerationId"
   where "EnumTable"='Vehicle Model')
   LOOP
     v_sql := v_sql
           || ',sum(case when "Text" is not null then 1 else 0)' || rec."Text";
    END LOOP;
  v_sql := v_sql
         || ',"pkEnumerationValueId" from "EnumerationValue" group by "Text","pkEnumerationValueId"';
 OPEN :g_ref FOR v_sql;
 END;
```

it is giving me error

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 14
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

My table column is "Text" containing values like "Suzuki","Ferrari","Honda","Ford" and it can be more (user can insert new values).
So I want a result like this.

```
Model        Suzuki        Ferrari     Honda      Ford   ........

2000           1              0          0          0
2001           5              2          5          0
2002           9              12         3          2
```

Comment: no, definitely not!! its not answered there. the answer contains hard coded values and if you can see the description, i want it dynamic. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your previous database and build a new database in order to solve this problem

Comment: I'm sorry that I ask a potentially dumb question, but ... How will this solve his problem?

Comment: if you know the other person, it might :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oracle SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE): "A subquery is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword."

In other words: You can't make a totally dynamic, on-an-enumeration-table-based pivoting query in static SQL without getting the output in XML.

What *can* you do, is use a dynamic SQL as in your second attempt with the `pivot` clause as in your first attempt and build up your `pivot for ... in ...` clause dynamically with "hardcoded" values.

Comment: i did tried it @nop77svk. my final resort is to make a temp table and create columns with the names of my rows. as oracle does not support this kind of thing.

Comment: Believe me, it works, I did it just yesterday on my project. Building up a pivoting select with dynamically "hardcoded" values and executing it via `execute immediate` or `open cursor for ...` would solve your problem. Unfortunately, I can't show you your resulting code, because I don't have time for it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your problems

1. Oracle does not support PIVOT/UNPIVOT until 11G.
2. You cannot make it totally dynamic to achieve transpose/pivot